# VueJS file upload not accepting file

Tags: vue.js, file-upload

I'm working on a file upload image preview with VueJS and I'm having an issue where...
1. - file get uploaded by user 
2. - preview comes up beside the input field 
3. - input field now says there is no image uploaded though there is the preview.

here is the html:

```
<input type='file' accept='image/*' @change="onChange" name='file'  />
<img width='200' :src="uploadPreview" alt='preview' />
```

here is my vueJs code:

```
    data: function() { return {
        uploadPreview : "",
        }
    },
    methods : {
        onChange(e) {
            if (! e.target.files.length) return;

            let file = e.target.files[0];

            let reader = new FileReader();

            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            reader.onload = e => {
                this.uploadPreview = e.target.result; // if this line is commented out or just not present, the upload will work but the preview won't show since uploadPreview does not have a value set.
                };
            },
     }
```

there's something with that line that I commented in the code there. 
`this.uploadPreview = e.target.result;` 
if this line is commented out or just not present, the upload will work but the preview won't show since uploadPreview does not have a value set.

Why is this not working? Why does the input field value for the file reset after simply setting `uploadPreview` to some binary image data??? Banging my head on this table once more.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you debugging points. Try and let me know.

```
data: function() { return {
        uploadPreview : "ABCD",
        }
    },
    methods : {
        onChange(e) {
            if (! e.target.files.length) return;

            let file = e.target.files[0];

            let reader = new FileReader();

            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            reader.onload = e => {
        console.log("FIRST SEE WHAT'S INSIDE THE RESULTS",e.target.result);
        console.log("SECOND MAKE SURE YOU CAN ACCESS",this.uploadPreview) // this should print ABCD
                this.uploadPreview = e.target.result; // if this line is commented out or just not present, the upload will work but the preview won't show since uploadPreview does not have a value set.
                };
            },
     }
```

and finally

```
<img width='200' :src="uploadPreview" :alt='uploadPreview' />
```

(alt should equals to image data)

Comment: Already tried that, logging to the console the before and after values and everything checks out. `file` stays the same object, `e.target.result` stays the same, and `this.uploadPreview` is the same as the result.

Comment: copy what you get for the uploadPreview and paste it as your src without semi colons. See that copied string can output the image correctly?